# Multiple actions - AwsCustomResource.on.. Is it possible?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, aws-iot

I've created a custom resource for creating a ThingType which is not yet implemented by AWS as simple CfnObjects. My code looks like this:

```
String physicalResIdThingType = "ThisISMyThing";
AwsCustomResource.Builder.create(this, "myThingType")
                .onCreate(AwsSdkCall.builder()
                        .service("Iot")
                        .action("createThingType")
                        .physicalResourceId(PhysicalResourceId.of(physicalResIdThingType))
                        .parameters(new HashMap() {{
                            put("thingTypeName", "myThingType");
                        }})
                        .build())
                .onDelete(AwsSdkCall.builder()
                        .service("Iot")
                        .action("deleteThingType")
                        .physicalResourceId(PhysicalResourceId.of(physicalResIdThingType))
                        .parameters(new HashMap() {{
                            put("thingTypeName", "myThingType");
                        }}).build())               .policy(AwsCustomResourcePolicy.fromSdkCalls(SdkCallsPolicyOptions.builder()
                        .resources(AwsCustomResourcePolicy.ANY_RESOURCE)
                        .build()))
                .installLatestAwsSdk(false)
                .resourceType(Consts.CUSTOM_RESOURCE_THING_TYPE)
                .build();
```

It is creating well. but not allowing me to delete the thing type because I need first to deprecate it and then delete it.. In the console we need to wait even 5 minutes after deprecation for complete deletion.

My questions are:

1. Is it possible to override this deprecation ?
2. If not, Is it possible to do multiple AwsSdkCalls without writing my own lambda functions ?
3. If none from above, then maybe someone has an idea how can I use this simple solution of `AwsCustomResource` to delete my thing type?

Answer (score 0):

I can only see one way to do it if you want the thing type to be deleted via cloudformation.

You can configure the `timeout-in-minutes` when call [cloudformation crate-stack](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/cloudformation/create-stack.html) . This value should be above than 5 minutes + extra buffer for the other resources to be deleted.

When you receive a DELETE event in your custom resource, you can deprecate the thing type, wait 5min and call delete thing type.